# How can I handle all the clicks on the component in angular4?

Tags: angular

I want to handle all the clicks on the component in one method.
How could I do that?

I have a component that represents single table row and its template looks like

```
<td style="text-align: right;">{{item.id}}</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">{{item.name}}</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">{{item.amount}}</td>
```

I want to catch all the clicks that could occur anywhere (any td). How could I do that?

Parent template is

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="itemsCollection">
      <app-tr [item]="item" style="display: table-row"></app-tr>
    </ng-template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I can add `(click)="someParentMethod($event)"` to the parent template, but I want to handle the event by the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your app-tr components class

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
myClickHandler(event) {...}
```

Comment: @D.S. glad to hear

Answer (score 1):

you also add click event of child component and send event from child to parent via EventEmiiter

for example

**Child component**

```
@Output onClick: EventEmiiter<any> = new EventEmiiter();

onclicking(){
this.onClick.emit('pass here you want');
}
```